# Modeling heteroscedastic selling data?

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, regression, forecasting

I have a model whose job it is to forecast the demand of a certain item for the upcoming weeks. I've formulated it as a regression problem and use many product-related features as well as current and historical selling data as covariates. I'm both interested in the expected demand as well as upper bounds/quantiles of the demand distribution. I'm using a combination of two techniques to do this. A tree ensemble with the MSE loss function to measure the expected value, and a heuristic that models the residuals on historical hold-out sets in order to calculate upper bounds and quantiles of error.

I've been planning to do a statistical significance test to see the impact that my model has had on the processes it controls. When reading up on the diff-in-diff test, I stumbled upon the fact that the diff-in-diff test is invalid if the variable you're performing the test on is [heteroscedastic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homoscedasticity_and_heteroscedasticity) as it leads to biased variance estimates. This made me think a bit and I ran a quick experiment with my original model where I log-transformed the target, which is one of the suggested remedies for heteroscedastic data. My results;

*Non-Log transformed target;*
[image: Non-Log transformed target]

*Log transformed target (exponential function reapplied after prediction);*
[image: Log transformed target (exponential function reapplied after prediction)]

In the plots above I've sorted my data by the size of the sales_target. The x-axis is simply the index of the sample in the dataframe whilst the y-axis is the prediction/target. I've also applied a 1000-sample wide centered rolling window to the predictions to get a smooth mean curve describing the average prediction for different ranges of the target. So this plot shows within which ranges of the target the model is biased, and in which direction. As you can see in the first plot which is the non-log transformed target, we have a positive bias on the lower target, and a negative bias on the higher ones. A problem I've seen many times during my career. But after log-transforming, this positive bias in the lower ranges seems to disappear.

Now to my question; Why does this happen? Is heteroscedasticity a serious issue that should be remedied for **all models** and not only OLS? It seems natural to me that variance should increase with the size of the dependent variable when measuring something like retail demand. Have I been using the wrong model?

Comment: Interesting question, but it's off topic here since it's not a specific programming problem; try stats.stackexchange.com instead.